# c code for receiving 8 bit data from hyperterminal to 89c51

Tags: c, embedded

I am doing home automation project but I don’t know how to enable particular pin I.e P1.0 enable when 8 bit data is received
Description:
consider, when I send 10011101 from hyper terminal then only P1.0 pin is enabled
when I send 10111100 from hyper terminal then only P1.1 pin is enabled

please send me c code

Comment: then why add `java` tag? and don't simply request for code without showing any effort

Comment: **please send me c code?** What is this? Show what you have done so far. This forum is not for getting your homework done by someone else.

Comment: sorry but I don't know anything about embedded c can you send link so I can prepare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you should understand is, You need to program your 89c51 controller to receive UART data. You can do that by following

1. It should initialize UART with baud rate in which your computer is operating.
2. Write UART Receive function which receives UART data and writes in to a buffer.
3. Compare received data with data which is expected.
4. If matches turn on corresponding pin of a micro controller.

You can find related information [here](http://www.atmel.in/tools/CODEEXAMPLESFOR8051UART.aspx) and [here](http://microcontrollerprojects00.blogspot.in/2012/04/89c51-serial-communication-tutorial.html)